# Homeomorphisms of the circle

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, reference-request, circles

I know that there is a vaste litterature about the group of the homeomorphisms of the circle. I would a good reference to start the study of this topic.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Guys, "Groups acting on the circle".

Comment: Ghys, not Guys.

Comment: Typo, sorry. Thanks for the correction.